# Problem with connecting and working with a PostgreSQL Database via a FLUTTER WEB APP

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I am getting the error here when I'm trying to connect and work with a `PostgreSQL` Database via a FLUTTER WEB APP.

Below is an example code to illustrate the issue.

Is there a solution or workaround to this problem/issue?

> Error:
>
> ```
> Error: Unsupported operation: Socket constructor
>     at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:4339:11)
>     at Function._connect (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:57607:17)
>     at Function.connect (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:57590:26)
>     at connection.PostgreSQLConnection.new.open (http://localhost:62530/packages/postgres/src/query_queue.dart.lib.js:3214:46)
>     at open.next (<anonymous>)
>     at runBody (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37699:34)
>     at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37730:7)
>     at connection.PostgreSQLConnection.new.open (http://localhost:62530/packages/postgres/src/query_queue.dart.lib.js:3205:20)
>     at main.ImageUploader.new.uploadDatatoDatabase (http://localhost:62530/packages/image_getter_app/main.dart.lib.js:701:25)
>     at uploadDatatoDatabase.next (<anonymous>)
>     at runBody (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37699:34)
>     at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37730:7)
>     at main.ImageUploader.new.uploadDatatoDatabase (http://localhost:62530/packages/image_getter_app/main.dart.lib.js:700:20)
>     at main.ImageUploader.new.uploadImage (http://localhost:62530/packages/image_getter_app/main.dart.lib.js:713:16)
>     at uploadImage.next (<anonymous>)
>     at http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37679:33
>     at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37533:58)
>     at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:32507:29)
>     at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:33054:49)
>     at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:33092:17)
>     at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:32935:23)
>     at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:32957:35)
>     at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37794:13)
>     at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:37800:13)
>     at http://localhost:62530/dart_sdk.js:33309:9
> ```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: image_getter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    SDK: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  file_picker: ^2.0.11
  postgres: ^2.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ImageUploader(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageUploader extends StatelessWidget {
  Uint8List imageValue;
  TextEditingController stringValue;
  TextEditingController intValue;

  final PostgreSQLConnection conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
    'localhost',
    5432,
    'dart_test',
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'password',
  );

  uploadDatatoDatabase() async {
    // NOTE Do this as part of DB setup, not in application code!
    // conn.query('''
    //  CREATE TABLE imageTable(
    //   id serial primary key not null,
    //   image_name text,
    //   image_size int,
    //   image_data bytea,
    // )
    // ''');

    await conn.open();

    print('Connected to Postgres database...');

    await conn.query('''
    INSERT INTO imageTable(image_name, image_size ,image_data)
    VALUES (${stringValue.text}, ${int.parse(intValue.text)}, ${imageValue})
    ''');

    await conn.close();
  }

  uploadImage() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'svg', 'jpeg']);

    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
      imageValue = file.bytes;
      uploadDatatoDatabase();
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
              child: Text(
                'Image Uploader',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Karla',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 50,
              child: TextField(
                controller: stringValue,
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(hintText: 'Just enter a random string'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 50,
              child: TextField(
                controller: intValue,
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(hintText: 'Just enter a random int'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        heroTag: 'picker',
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent[400],
        hoverElevation: 0,
        label: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.file_upload),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('Upload Image')
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () => uploadImage(),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it's not supported, you can't create Socket objects in a web browser

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're attempting to run this code in the browser. `Postgresql` doesn't work from the browser.

Normally database access is managed by a service running on a server and the browser sends calls to this service to store and retrieve data and then the service forwards the request to the database.

Comment: Can you please give any examples of such service?